# Proguard - any way to ignore incompatible (due to Java bytecode version) packages in external library?

Tags: java, windows, proguard

I have a desktop `Java` project (compiled with an older JRE as target). The simplified structure of my `.pro` file is:

```
-injars qtt.jar
-outjars qtt_obf.jar
-libraryjars \Libraries\wsp.jar
```

`wsp.jar` is offered by a 3rd-party that includes `Java 9`-specific packages, e.g. `META-INF\versions\9\com.xyz.prod\<various_other_folders>`. At this time, [Java 9 support is not available](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/feature-requests/181/), hence `Proguard` complains about the presence of classes with version `53.0`.

Is there any way to make `Proguard` "skip" these external dependencies (and, fo course, not break the application at runtime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that filters are a lifesaver here: changing your example so it reads

```
-injars qtt.jar
-outjars qtt_obf.jar
-libraryjars \Libraries\wsp.jar(!META-INF/**)
```

will filter out all the stuff in META-INF -- including the version 9 classfiles you are trying to get rid of. See more details in the page below.

https://www.guardsquare.com/proguard/manual/usage#filefilters

Comment: That is pretty much what I did, by modifying the jar itself. It seems I missed a few lines from the docs.